# ImportError: No module named 'flask_jwt_extended' in PYTHON FLASK

Tags: python-3.x, flask

In localhost:5000 the script is running without any errors, but when it comes to symlink an error has been thrown to appache log.

```
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170057 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852] mod_wsgi (pid=30438): Exception occurred processing$
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170435 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170461 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852]   File "/var/www/html/salesappserver/app.wsgi", lin$
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170465 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852]     from api import app as application
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170471 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852]   File "/var/www/html/salesappserver/api.py", line $
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170474 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852]     from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:16.170491 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30438] [client 120.29.113.65:32852] ImportError: No module named 'flask_jwt_extended'
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.501917 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858] mod_wsgi (pid=30439): Target WSGI script '/var/www/$
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.501994 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858] mod_wsgi (pid=30439): Exception occurred processing$
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.502345 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.502372 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858]   File "/var/www/html/salesappserver/app.wsgi", lin$
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.502376 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858]     from api import app as application
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.502382 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858]   File "/var/www/html/salesappserver/api.py", line $
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.502393 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858]     from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
[Sun Jun 10 17:07:17.502411 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 30439] [client 120.29.113.65:32858] ImportError: No module named 'flask_jwt_extended'
```

This is the main problem:

> ImportError: No module named 'flask_jwt_extended'

which I already satisfied the requirement in FLASK

```
(salesappserver) ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-35:~$ pip install flask-jwt-extended
Requirement already satisfied: flask-jwt-extended in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-jwt-extended) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyJWT in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-jwt-extended) (1.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-jwt-extended) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-jwt-extended) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-jwt-extended) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-jwt-extended) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./salesappserver/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask->flask-jwt-extended) (1.0)
(salesappserver) ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-35:~$
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please note than on ubuntu machines, `pip` refers to python27's version of pip  by default (thanks to [PEP394](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)). If you have developed this app to run on python3, then you should use `pip3 install flask-jwt-extended` instead and for that you'll have to first do `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: Still, the terminal returns that requirements were already satisfied when i type pip3 install flask-jwt-extended.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? If so, have you configured uwsgi to use that instance of python instead of the system one?

Comment: @vimalloc i already configured my uwgi. i dont know what is the problem when it comes to it. in virtual environment, the script running well and no errors. do you have some idea why uwgsi cant read flask-jwt-extended?

Comment: Have do you have your uwsgi setup to use the vent, and what version of uwsgi are you running. I very much suspect that is the problem.

Comment: yes i have already configured it. any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `flask-jwt-extended` module. Get the package by running following command and then try again.

```
pip install flask-jwt-extended
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run python as service or not in the user environment, you have to install with the package with **apt-get install python3-python-flask-jwt-extended**

In ubuntu try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-python-flask python3-python-flask-jwt-extended -y
```

If you want to run in user environment with python 2.x

```
pip install flask flask_jwt_extended
```

at python 3.x install by this:

```
pip3 install flask flask_jwt_extended
```